# Как создать HtmlHelper с помощью Razor в отдельном файле

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Если создавать @helper в файле представления, в котором его и использовать, никаких проблем, но захламлять не хочется разметку. При этом, не хочется использовать методы расширения из-за отсутствия поддержки Razor.

Можно ли как-то написать хелпер при помощи Razor при этом разместив в отдельном файле? По идее, должно быть можно создать файл .cshtml там все описать, а потом использовать где угодно сославшись на него. Но не получается, VS не видит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общие Razor-хэлперы нужно размещать в специальном каталоге `App_Code`. Каталог создается через контекстное меню на проекте -> Add -> Add ASP.NET Folder -> App_Code. Если хэлпер создать в каталоге Views, то к нему действительно нельзя обратиться.

В представлении хэлпер доступен как `@ИмяФайлаСХэлпером.ИмяХэлпера(...)`. Если IntelliSense при этом выдает ошибки (подчеркивает код красным), то пересоберите проект.

Каталог `App_Code` нужно деплоить на сервер вместе с приложением.

Comment: Благодарю. Нашел еще простой гайд отвечабющий на тот же вопрос, может кому пригодится. http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site